# CSS3 hyphens not applied

Tags: css, word-wrap, hyphenation

I'm trying to add automatic CSS3 hyphens to my articles. Problem is the tag doesn't seem to affect the text.

I set

```
.entry p {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
}
```

... but nothing happens.

[Here](http://bombacarta.com/2013/12/01/pietra-enigma-senso-e-valore/)'s an example page I'm talking about (BTW you won't see the above CSS in real site, but I tried with Firebug).

Comment: Does it work if you put a bunch of random english text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this case is a missing `lang` attribute. Without that defined, the web browsers do no know how to hyphenate the page, because they don't know what language they are hyphenating in.

Adding this attribute will fix the issue in browsers that support hyphenation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which browser you are using.

According to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/), Chrome and Android browser actually support -webkit-hyphens: none, which is the default value, but none of the other values.

And, in Firefox and Internet Explorer, automatic hyphenation only works for some languages (defined with the lang attribute).

Edit: Here is the [Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Browser_compatibility), which says "This is an experimental technology".

Comment: The `lang` attribute isn't defined on the reference page. Perhaps try adding it, and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @randak was right. with lang attribute now it works even in non-english langs :)

Comment: @randak Let's help others find the answer: randak can add an answer (instead of the comment), and then Multiformelngegno can accept that answer.

Comment: Adding an answer. Didn't before because I missed the comment saying it had worked, and hadn't had time to test it myself.